# Как сделать видимым дочерний элемент при клике?

Tags: vue.js

[вывожу массив фалов](https://jsfiddle.net/demeys/eywraw8t/462223/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    arr: [{
        name: 'afaw',
      },
      {
        name: 'argeae',
      },
      {
        name: 'agsesf',
      }
    ],
    loading: false,

  },
  methods: {
    deleteFile(index) {
      this.loading = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.common.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item,i) in arr">

      <div class="p-2 overflow-hidden">

        <small class="text-gray">{{item.name}} </small>

        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-1 float-right" @click="deleteFile(i)">
                   <i v-if="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
              </button>

      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

При клике на кнопку deleteFile задаю this.loading = true;
но он срабатывает для всего списка, как сделать чтоб loading был только у конкретной кнопки?

Comment: `this.arr[index].loading = true;` – в каждом элементе массива для этого нужно держать переменную

Comment: ну можно передать соыбите и уже от неего оталкиватся  @click="deleteFile(i, $event)"

Comment: как варинт использовать вычисляемые свйоства computed:{
            loader() {
                return this.loading;
            } 
        }